# Pi Pico C++ code doesn't autorun after reset

Tags: reset, boot, raspberry-pi-pico, rp2040

I have a simple blink code for the NeoPixel LED (WS2812) written in C++, which I'm running on the Waveshare RP2040-Zero board.

When I upload the UF2 file to my Pico, USB disconnects as expected, Pico reboots and the LED is working.
However it appears the program is lost after any kind of reset. It doesn't autorun the code after re-plug or after pressing the reset button.

I tried uploading the same code written in MicroPython and it survives the resets. It's only the C++ code that has issues.
Also running the same UF2 file on second Pico proves the code is correct.

I saw similar issues on the internet, but there weren't any clear answers.
Has anyone had such problems?
Do you think it's a hardware issue, as I see it only on one of my Picos?

Comment: If it starts working after attaching serial monitor, then it's blocked by `while (!Serial);`. But as you didn't provide the code, it's just a wild guess